# Mapping a a simple collection of elements with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, collections

I'm trying to map a collection of enum values with Fluent NHibernate.

```
IList<EnumType> lst;
```

I can't find any documentation about it but I'm quite sure it should be possible.
I had no problem at all with mapping a collection of Entities.

Thanks,
Leonardo

Comment: It was quite simple, you just need to use Element("") tag in the Fluent Nhibernate mappaing for the collection.

Comment: Then write out a full proper answer and accept it.  That way people can still upvote it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following FNH mapping signature to map simple value type collections.

```
HasMany(x => x.Collection)
    .Table("TableName")
    .KeyColumn("KeyColumnName")
    .Element("ValueColumnName");
```

Where:

- Collection: the collection of value types (can be `enum` because that will be mapped as int).
- TableName: the name of the table that will store your collection values.
- KeyColumnName: the name of the column that will store the key value back to the parent.
- ValueColumnName : the name of the column that will store the actual value.

Lets see an example of how to map a few collections of value types.

```
public enum EnumType
{
    Value1,
    Value2,
    Value3
}

public class Entity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Primary key
    /// </summary>
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Collection of strings
    /// </summary>
    public virtual IList<string> StringCollection { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Collection of enums
    /// </summary>
    public virtual IList<EnumType> EnumCollection { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Collection of dates/times
    /// </summary>
    public virtual IList<DateTime> DateTimeCollection { get; set; }
}

public class EntityMap : ClassMap<Entity>
{
    public EntityMap()
    {
        // Map primary key.
        Id(x => x.Id);

        // Map value collections
        HasMany(x => x.StringCollection)
            .Table("Entity_String")
            .KeyColumn("EntityId")
            .Element("String");

        HasMany(x => x.EnumCollection)
            .Table("Entity_Enum")
            .KeyColumn("EntityId")
            .Element("Enum");

        HasMany(x => x.DateTimeCollection)
            .Table("Entity_DateTime")
            .KeyColumn("EntityId")
            .Element("DateTime");
    }
}
```

The result of this mapping will produce four (4) tables.

1. Table Entity with one column Id of int.
2. Table Entity_String with two columns - EntityId : int, String : varchar, and a foreign key EntityId to Entity table Id column.
3. ... likewise, except column is of int type.
4. ... likewise, except column is of datetime type.

Comment: How to define the length of the element column (ValueColumnName)?

Answer (score 2):

HasMany(x => x.Items)
    .Table("tbl")
    .KeyColumn("fk")
    .Element("eCol")
    .AsBag()